# Common elements by columns in high-dimensional matrix

Tags: r, dplyr, intersection, intersect, dimensional

I have a data like **original** with much more columns.

```
id <- c('A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G')
month <- c('NA', 'D', 'H', 'I', 'A', 'B', 'NA')
iso <- c('NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'NA')
original <- data.frame(id, month, iso)
```

I want to create a string containing all common elements found in the columns, like string **common**:

```
common <- c("A", "B")
```

I have found posts like:
[R: How can I find the intersection of elements from two rows of a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592350/r-how-can-i-find-the-intersection-of-elements-from-two-rows-of-a-dataframe)
or like:
[How to find common elements from multiple vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695677/how-to-find-common-elements-from-multiple-vectors)

But these posts do not make the trick. In such a high-dimensional dataset I need something "less manual".

Any clue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
reduce(original, intersect)
#[1] "A" "B"
```

Answer (score 3):

One options could be:

```
Reduce(`intersect`, original)

[1] "A" "B"
```

Comment: Good one! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
library(RVenn)
overlap(Venn(original))
# [1] "A" "B"
```

Comment: That is a new info for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. convert data into a list (actually the dataset was a list originally)
2. then:

```
unli_df <- unlist(df)
unique(unli_df)
```